# apt-show-versions stretch

Tags: debian, apt

2 days ago I upgraded from jessie to stretch.  After an upgrade I always use

```
dpkg -l | egrep '^ii' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt-show-versions | egrep -v new release-name` to identfy and purge packages from old release. But now something went wrong with apt-show-version. `head -n20 /root/apt-show-versions 
accountsservice:i386 not installed
acl:i386 not installed
acpi:i386 not installed
acpi-fakekey:i386 not installed
acpid:i386 not installed
alsa-base:all 1.0.27+1 installed: No available version in archive
alsa-utils:i386 not installed
alsaplayer-gtk:i386 not installed
amd64-microcode:i386 not installed
anacron:i386 not installed
apache2-bin:i386 not installed
apmd:i386 not installed
apt:i386 not installed
apt-transport-https:i386 not installed
apt-utils:i386 not installed
aptdaemon:all 1.1.1-4+deb8u1 installed: No available version in archive
aptdaemon-data:all 1.1.1-4+deb8u1 installed: No available version in archive
aptitude:i386 not installed
aptoncd:all 0.1.98+bzr117-1.4 installed: No available version in archive
arp-scan:i386 not installed
```

I'm not intrested what is not installed.

Request for 1 package:

```
dpkg -l | grep xwayland | xargs apt-show-versions 
2 not available for architecture 1.19.2-1+deb9u1
Use of uninitialized value $arch in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 370.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 373.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 385.
X: not installed
Use of uninitialized value $arch in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 370.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 373.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 385.
Xwayland: not installed
Use of uninitialized value $arch in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 370.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 373.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 385.
amd64: not installed
Use of uninitialized value $arch in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 370.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 373.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 385.
ii: not installed
Use of uninitialized value $arch in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 370.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 373.
Use of uninitialized value $arch in hash element at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 385.
server: not installed
xwayland:amd64/stretch 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u1 uptodate
xwayland:i386 not installed
```

How can I avoid it. `apt-show-versions -V
Apt-Show-Versions v.0.22.6 (c) Christoph Marti`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep -o package-name | xargs apt-show-versions
```

Instead of

```
dpkg -l | grep package-name | xargs apt-show-versions
```

To see only the  package to be upgraded you can use:

```
apt-show-versions | grep upgradeable
```

The obsolete package can be listed through:

```
apt-show-versions | grep 'No available version'
```

Comment: I need apt-show-versions for all installed packages. I never hat problems with my command. `dpkg -l | grep -o xwayland | xargs apt-show-versions 
xwayland:amd64/stretch 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u1 uptodate
xwayland:i386 not installed`

Comment: I found another possibility `apt list | egrep -vi 'stable|stretch'